# Using Split Parts tool more than once in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting, polygon-creation

Why in QGIS 3.10 can I only use the Split Parts tool on a polygon once?

The second time throws an error of:

> "Geometry is invalid"

What if i want to split a polygon into three separate parts?

I've found one question like this, where the OP moved away the split polygon, but I need to keep the geometry as is, only have 3 parts of a single polygon.

Before:
[image]

After: (The green line is the second split i need.)
[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the polygon in question before and after splitting it.

Comment: Its a polygon of river body, i need to split only the deepest part. The green line indicates the second cut.

Comment: Have you tried undoing the split and then redoing it?

Comment: @Erik Yes, i have tried everything, restarting, cutting different polygons, all you can think of. The result is always the same "Invalid geometry"... I have found a workaround, that is splitting the polygon with a single line, going around it, since the water bodies arent as big. But i cant imagine doing it for a very long polygon.

Comment: Could you proide parts of your data so we could have a look at it?

Comment: @Erik Unforunately i can't do that, since the data is not mine, however you can simply draw any polygon, edit it split it in half using "split parts" (not split feature!), and then try to split the half into another half. It won't work. I ran validity check, and it isnt a valid polygon. Using fix geometry merges the halves together.

Comment: Why is it important you use `split parts` instead of `split feature`?

Comment: @Erik Because i want all the parts to be in a single feature/multipart

Comment: Your multipolygon has an overlapping border with itself, hence it is a faulty geometry. If you used `split feature` this issue wouldn't appear.

Comment: @So there is not simple way of splitting a polygon into several parts? Why should be overlapping parts a problem, in Arcgis you never run into such issue

Comment: Then feel free to use Arcgis, if QGIS doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: @Erik, I can't bcz im not a student anymore and dont have a licence. But nvm, thanks for the efford :)

Comment: I don't see how ArcGIS would produce different results.   Multiparts share a single table row but they are separate shapes although they might touch at one point in what is called a bow tie, which is generally considered undesireable.  If you want to split your polygon into three separate polygons use the split features tool.

Comment: @johns I was just curious, why i can create a 3 in 1 multipart by drawing a single line that goes around the polygon, but not by two seperate drawings. The idea of this was to indicate where the main stream of the river flows, while keeping the 2 shallow coasts in the same feature for the sake of flood modeling. I dont see why 2 parts of a single polygon are fine, but 3 are not. However it's not a pressing issue and solution of 3 separate polygons is of course plausible.

Comment: @XDOLK009 I don't think the "2 parts" works either although I'm a bit surprised it does produce a polygon that can be saved.  The polygon has a self-intersection geometry error, however, and while self intersection errors can often be ignored, many tools won't run on them and that's probably why you can't do a third "split".  If you run a fix geometries on it you'll get back your original polygon.  If you run multipart to single part you get a split like a split features would do.  So there's no gain, just pain.

Comment: @johns Yes you are right, thanks for the help :) Have a nice day

Comment: @XDOLK009 - I suggest you post your comments as an answer.